# NPM dependencies shared by dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, npm-install

On npm 3.3.12 (node 4.2.2), the following thing happen:

I run `npm install` in a project where one of the dependencies in my project is also a dependency of one of the other dependencies. For instance:

- My project depend on PackageA and PackageB
- PackageA also depend on PackageB
- Both My project and PackageA depend on the same verison of PackageB

Then, I run `npm update` in my prroject. The NPM output lists:

```
PackageB@x.x.x node_modules/PackageB -> node_modules/PackageA/node_modules/PackageB
```

So then suddenly PackageB is not in node_modules of my project (only in node_modules under PackageA) and require("PackageB") in the files of the project fails.

What is causing this, and how can I best avoid the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug, fixed in NPM 3.4.1:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10446