# NPM nested dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am developing a module that I try to make as generic as possible (let's say BaseModule), and I want to extend it to feet my current purposes in another module (let's say ChildModule).

So ChildModule begins with:

```
require('BaseModule');
```

So I added `BaseModule` as a dependency of `ChildModule`. But when I want to use both of them on my real project, I cannot install both of them. Installing `BaseModule` removes `ChildModule`, and installing `ChildModule` moves `BaseModule`, in a way it is unreachable in my code afterward.

Both the module are on a git repository only (ie not published yet).

---

What is funny is that mongoose is also a dependency of `ChildModule`, and I don't have this issue. So I think I forgot something in `BaseModule`, but I don't know what...

It is a bit similar to this issue [NPM dependencies shared by dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750940/npm-dependencies-shared-by-dependencies), which is supposed to be fixed on my NPM version (5.6). This [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16794) is also similar, but as I said before I don't think it is a bug.

---

Is there any way to have nested dependency? If no, what is the standard way to do this kind of extension?

---

Here are the different package.json:

BaseModule's package.json

```
{
  "name": "BaseModule",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://.../BaseModule.git"
  },
  "bundledDependencies": false,
  }
```

ChildModule:

```
{
  "name": "ChildModule",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://.../ChildModule.git"
  },
  "bundledDependencies": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^4.13.9",
    "BaseModule": ".../BaseModule"

  }
}
```

and the project itself:

```
{
  "name": "Project", 
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^4.13.9",
    "ChildModule": ".../ChildModule",
    "BaseModule": ".../BaseModule",
    "andALotMore": "*"
  }
}
```

`...` stands for the correct address of my repositories.

Comment: Can you show an abbreviated version of all 3 projects `package.json`s?

Comment: Done, see edit! Thanks.